# Set Hidden Value Depending on Selection of two Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set a hidden value depending on the values set for two different dropdown boxes.

Here is what I have so far, it is not working, I expect it to set the value of #bundle_option[5] to 4 when the dropdown #bundle-option-5-color is set to Black and #bundle-option-5-size is set to Child.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#bundle-option-5-color').change(function() {
        if ($j(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'Black' &&
            $j('#bundle-option-5-size').find('option:selected').text() == 'Child')
        {
        $j('#bundle_option\\[5\\]').val('4');
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="bundle-option-5-color" name="bundle_option[5]" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Purple">Purple</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Teal">Teal</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
</select>

<select id="bundle-option-5-size" name="bundle_option[5]" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Child">Child</option>
<option value="Youth">Youth</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
<option value="Adult X-Large">Adult X-Large</option>
<option value="Adult XX-Large">Adult XX-Large</option>
</select>

<input id="bundle_option[5]" type="hidden" value="" name="bundle_option[5]">
```

Comment: You're only checking when the color changes, not when the size changes, so if you change the color and then the size, the condition won't be checked like you expect. Fix that and it should work fine.

Comment: As j08691 suggested you should probably do something like this `$j('#bundle-option-5-color, #bundle-option-5-size').change(function() { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your function to the both `change` events:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fn = function() {
        if ($('#bundle-option-5-color').find('option:selected').text() == 'Black' &&
            $('#bundle-option-5-size').find('option:selected').text() == 'Child')
        {
          
        $('#bundle_option\\[5\\]').val('4');
        }

    }; 
    $('#bundle-option-5-color').change(fn);
    $('#bundle-option-5-size').change(fn);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bundle-option-5-color" name="bundle_option[5]" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Purple">Purple</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Teal">Teal</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
</select>

<select id="bundle-option-5-size" name="bundle_option[5]" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Child">Child</option>
<option value="Youth">Youth</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
<option value="Adult X-Large">Adult X-Large</option>
<option value="Adult XX-Large">Adult XX-Large</option>
</select>

<input id="bundle_option[5]" type="text" value="" name="bundle_option[5]">
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to trigger your function for both option box change events. You can do that with this wildcard selector `$('[id^=bundle-option-5]').change(function() {})`.

Please find your code below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/5sst9mhk/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=bundle-option-5]').change(function() {
        //console.log(this);
        // size or color changed
        if ($('#bundle-option-5-color').find('option:selected').text() == 'Black' &&
            $('#bundle-option-5-size').find('option:selected').text() == 'Child')
        {
        $('#bundle_option\\[5\\]').val('4');
          alert('black and child chosen!');
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bundle-option-5-color" name="bundle_option[5]" change-container-classname"="" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Purple">Purple</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Teal">Teal</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
</select>

<select id="bundle-option-5-size" name="bundle_option[5]" change-container-classname"="" bundle-option-select="" required-entry="" required="">
<option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
<option value="Child">Child</option>
<option value="Youth">Youth</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
<option value="Adult X-Large">Adult X-Large</option>
<option value="Adult XX-Large">Adult XX-Large</option>
</select>

<input id="bundle_option[5]" type="hidden" value="" name="bundle_option[5]">
```